# Some users missing styles after switching to CDN on rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, cdn

I have a rails application hosted on Heroku. Recently we switched to use a CDN (cloudfront) for our assets. Although we faced problems with CORS, we were able to get it all sorted out with the font_assets gem and proper tuning of cloudfront.

We are having a few select users (two reported so far, each on latest chrome 40+) not downloading the assets and therefore having no styling of the page.

Why would this happen to select users? Some things I've noticed that might help:

- There are a lot of 3xx responses recorded in cloudfront (more than
  2xx)
- Around the time that the user loaded an unstyled page, a 304 response was returned for the css file.

Comment: I have to ask the obvious questions: Did these users reload the page? Same result?

Comment: Do you use fragment caching in your Rails application?